# Javascript/Json : Object of object converted to associative array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, express

With AngularJS, I send the following data to my API :

```
$http.post('/api/test', { credits: { value:"100", action:"test" } });
```

In my nodeJS (+Express) backend, I get the following data :

[image]

Why does my post data have been converted to an associative array ?

What i'd like to have instead is :

```
credits : Object
      action : "test"
      velue  : "100"
```

Comment: I'd suggest using body-parser, https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: yes I'm using express, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: There's an example in the docs http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: @davcs86 : Does it mean I'm doing nothing "wrong" and this is a wierd behaviour of the native body parser ?

Comment: That is just how your parser is rendering it in your inspector. You still reference the values as an object. eg: credits.action or credits.value

Comment: @buzzsaw The problem is it then breaks a "for...in" loop I'd like to not modify. (because the property is "credits[value]" instead of "value")

Comment: @buzzsaw No it's not just the display, the properties have been flattened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [body-parser](http://npmjs.com/package/body-parser) package, with the option "extended" as true,

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/test',function (req, res) {
  var data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.credits);
  console.log(data.credits.value);
  console.log(data.credits.action);

  var result = "";
  for (var key in data.credits) {
    if (data.credits.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + data.credits[key]);
      result += key + " -> " + data.credits[key];
    }
  }

  res.send(result);
  res.end();
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){

});
```

results in console

```
{ credits: { value: '100', action: 'test' } }
{ value: '100', action: 'test' }
100
test
value -> 100
action -> test
```